# JQuery .html() doesnt return selfclosing tags correctly

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I want to get the HTML inside a specific div class. I used .html() but it returns self closing tags (ex: br, hr) without closing tag. Please advice how to get correct result set.

HTML

```
<div class="bimage-text">
<p>dssds</p>
<hr class="divider-line"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.bimage-text').html()
```

OUTPUT

```
<div class="bimage-text">
<p>dssds</p>
<hr class="divider-line">
</div>
```

Expected output

```
<div class="bimage-text">
<p>dssds</p>
<hr class="divider-line"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `<hr class="divider-line"/>` is not valid HTML, it's XHTML. This also doesn't have anything to do with jQuery, since it just uses the vanilla `innerHTML` property of the element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: @LucaKiebel thanks for info